# Resetting a CSS transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

I want to resize an element with a CSS transition and then reset the element to its original size and restart the animation. Here's the code:

```
$('#Bar').css('transition', 'none');
$('#Bar').css('-webkit-transition', 'none');
$('#Bar').css('width', 200);
$('#Bar').css('transition', 'width 3s');
$('#Bar').css('-webkit-transition', 'width 3s');
$('#Bar').css('width', 0);
```

The jsFiddle is **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/s5pmxy30/)**. As you can see, when you click on the resize button using JavaScript the element resizes and the animation restarts. However, it's not working as expected using CSS. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use animation instead of transition and use `animation: name 5s forwards;`. I made example for you http://jsfiddle.net/xsozar7m/4/

CSS:

```
#box {
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.active {
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: mymov 5s forwards;
    animation: mymov 5s forwards;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

@-webkit-keyframes mymov {
    from {width: 100px;}
    to {width: 0px;}
}

@keyframes mymov {
    from {width: 100px;}
    to {width: 0px;}
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
   $('#box').removeClass('active');
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#box').addClass('active');
},10);
});
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="box"></div>
 <button>Start</button>
```

Comment: Where's the button that controls the start??

Comment: That triggers one animation but it doesn't restart it. Look at the jsFiddle in the question, click on the ResizeJS button every 2 seconds and you'll see what I'm looking for.

Comment: Ok, this is great, this is the answer. Make sure to put the code that's in the jsFiddle in your answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Here's the jsFiddle where I modified your code to extract just the logic of your answer: http://jsfiddle.net/xsozar7m/6/ Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Actually I answered on your exact question :) But ok, here is the full solution of what you need http://jsfiddle.net/s5pmxy30/5/

Comment: No, I meant put the code that's in the fiddle in your answer so that other people can see the core code on the page without having to go elsewhere.