# Multiple rotate and scale transition not working

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I want to apply a rotation and zoom out and in transition between states of rotation of an image when a specific trigger happens. The zoom out and in should occurs durring the rotation.

https://jsfiddle.net/1dq3zo05/46/

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  image.style.transform = 'scale(4) rotate(' + ja + 'deg) scale(0.25)';
  image.style.transition = 'transform 2s ease-in-out';
  ja+=90;
});
```

This code works for the first transition, but not for any other.

I have seen some code with states or @keyframe but none of them worked for that simple case.

Comment: Use animation instead of transition:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27283300/resetting-a-css-transition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a wrapper and rotate it, and apply the scale animation to the image.
Something like this:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const imgWrapp = document.querySelector('.img-wrapp');
  if ( imgWrapp.classList.contains('animated') ) {
    return;
  }
  imgWrapp.style.setProperty( '--rotate', Number( getComputedStyle(imgWrapp).getPropertyValue('--rotate') ) + 90 );
  imgWrapp.classList.add('animated');
  setTimeout( () => imgWrapp.classList.remove('animated'), 2000 );
});
```

```css
.img-wrapp {
  --rotate: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: transform 2s;
  transform: rotate(calc(var(--rotate) * 1deg));
}

.img-wrapp.animated img {
  animation: rotate 2s both;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  33.333% {
    transform: scale(4);
  }
  66.666% {
    transform: scale(.25);
  }
}
```

```html
<button>Turn the image</button>
<div class="img-wrapp">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/8kGmXwB.png" alt="Light Bulb">
</div>
```